# Do we always use Sophie-Germain primes $1\bmod 4$?

Tags: discrete-logarithm, prime-numbers

A prime $p$ is Sophie Germain if $2p+1$ is also prime. [Wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sophie_Germain_prime#Modular_restrictions) says if $p\equiv3\bmod4$ then $2p+1|2^p-1$. This seems to put a huge restriction on density of Sophie-Germain prime if they are $3\bmod4$. For this reason do all systems use Sophie-Germain primes with $1\bmod 4$ for discrete logarithm?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> This seems to put a huge restriction on density of Sophie-Germain prime if they are $3 \bmod 4$.

I'm not sure how you come to that conclusion; whether $2p+1$ is a factor of $2^p-1$ would not have any immediately obvious consequence to $2p+1$ being prime.

> For this reason do all systems use Sophie-Germain primes with $1 \bmod 4$ for discrete logarithm?

Actually, Sophie-Germain primes of the form $3 \bmod 4$ would appear to be more prevalent; for example, [the primes listed here](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/rfc3526/) are all of the form $3 \bmod 4$.  One reason is that it makes the value $g=2$ be a quadratic residue, that is, its use during the DH operation doesn't leak the lsbit of the private exponent, and that's appreciated by some people.

Comment: could you explain on 'its use during the DH operation doesn't leak the lsbit of the private exponent'? I though lsbit is always leaked no matter what.

Comment: @Turbo: sure; in DH, Alice picks a random value $a$ and transmites $g^a \bmod p$; if $g$ is a primitive element, anyone can test if $g^a$ is a quadratic residue; if it is, then the lsbit of $a$ is a 0; otherwise it is a 1.  If $g$ is a quadratic residue, then that test tells people nothing (as $g^a \bmod p$ is always a quadratic residue).

Comment: so $1\bmod 4$ and $3\bmod 4$ Sophie-Germain prime densities are believed similar?

Comment: @Turbo: as far as I know; a quick count of the ones under 100,000,000 shows a slight edge to the $3 \bmod 4$ (211,439 vs 211,700)...

Comment: 3 mod 4 has a very small lead at 1e9 and 1e10 as well, but loses it by 2e10 (20,000,000,000).  It's extremely close at 1e11 with 3 mod 4 leading  by a very small amount.

Comment: @poncho what do you mean by 'DH operation doesn't leak the lsbit of the private exponent'? I thought that bit is always leaked in discrete logarithm

Comment: @Turbo: that is incorrect; if $g$ is a quadratic residue, then the lsbit is not leaked; see my previous comment.  In fact, if the lsbit is leaked in the case that the order of $g$ is odd, then the attacker can efficiently compute the entire dlog (in order words, the lsbit is a *hard bit*)